# Best Practice to save data and images on App

Tags: android, firebase

I want to design an App to display short stories and images belong to this story.
I think I have two scenarios:

1. a-  save the data in SQLite and attached with the app.

   b- save images in a drawable folder.
   (But the App size will be big because of the images saved in drawable folder)
2. save data and images on server and App pull the data.

**My questions:**

**1**: Which is the best scenario 1 or 2?

**2**: in case I choose the scenario -2- is possible to use firebase, like I want to put the data and images on the firebase and just the apps are authorized to pull these data?

**3**: Any new scenario for best practice to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

I choose **second** one.

1. We can include dynamic content.
2. Small APK size.
3. If new story comes, no update to your App. the existing app will show the new story.
4. Not only one include thousands, lacks, millions oru trillions

Firebase is currently Available best option. Only the difficulty is designing the data storing in the firebase. And you can fetch dynamically or first time. and Fcm push notification, you can include if you insert new stories.

For image you can use different libraries.Fresco, Glide, Picasso

---

And Another option is Designing your own server. It include other programming knowledge and a host also

But fcm free pack only 100 connections are allowed at a time.

Comment: Thank you for quick respond, How to make my app authorized to pull the data, I could n't find any tutorials to do that

Comment: integrate the firebase into your app.Follow this tutorial
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 0):

**Choose Firebase.**
This will give you the flexibility to update the content (Images/Stories) remotely. Firebase Database you can use to store the text data and Firebase Storage to store the media files.